# Use Application Insights to view all REST API requests per user

Tags: asp.net-web-api, analytics, azure-application-insights

We are developing a WebApi2 application. Users can use the REST API using their specific API key. I am investigating how to setup Application Insights to be able to see the usage of the REST API endpoints per user.

I have been experimenting with using telemetryclient.TrackPageview(endpoint-ID) and telemetryclient.TrackEvent(endpoint-ID), but I am not sure if this is the right way to go. And how should I pass the user-ID (API-key) in the tracking call? As telemetryclient.Context.User.Id? Or using properties or some other way? I would like to be able to use the user-ID to aggregate/segment the pageviews/events that were registered for that particular user. Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the built in properties, like context.user.id whenever possible, and then custom properties after that.

Currently in the portal, from the search view you can then find an item for any user, then use the "related items" to view "all telemetry for this user" to see all of the items.

Then can use the  [App Analytics portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-analytics/)  to do queries (click the "analytics" button toolbar in the overview blade for your resource azure portal to go to the AA site for that resource), and that service lets you write much richer queries.

[image]

in those queries, it's easiest to group/filter on the "built in" properties, for custom properties you have to write a little bit more complicated queries to parse the values out of custom code.